# Brahmin warriors defending religion eg Somnath

Tags: dharma, death, brahmins, war, parashurama

Parasurama was a Brahman and a great warrior. Apart from Brahmavidya, Brahmans also learn shastra of fighting, war and weapons. When Somnath was attacked by Mahmud of Ghazni, Raj Navghans Commander and Minister Mahidhar and Shridhar - both Nagar Brahmans - laid down their lives to protect the temple of Lord Shiva.
Are there any more famous examples?

Comment: Hi there is no question in the post just some information.. pls add a question too

Comment: Agree. Was giving an example and looking for more instances which may be known by others.

Comment: Thanks for adding the question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sir

Answer (score 1):

According to some story, King Pours who fought Alexander was a brahmin. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFp94kJWWSg

Comment: Well, how did I forgot the most ill famous Hindu king RAWANA!